# Sharepoint 2013-Web Part with dynamic links & not search driven

Tags: dashboard, sharepoint-2013

I have 2 sites, and only me as the resource. One is a forms portal and one is a reports portal. The goal of the sites is to standardize the locations of both types of documents.

The Challenge:

I need to have a "UI" with little to no coding, that doesn't require access to VS. And the "UI" list of forms/reports needs to be "quasi-automatically updated"

What I did:
I created a list with the document(s) name, contact, & URL in it for each site we'll call "MASTER_FORMS_LIST" & "MASTER_Submitted_Forms_List".

The original intent was to create a page w/ web parts and have the page be 1/2 "Submitted_forms_list" and 1/2 "New_Forms_list" and tie it to the two master lists....so when someone adds a form, they only have to add the URL's for the forms and the "UI" will be updated automatically by SP.
The goal being to NOT allow someone to mess up the UI showing forms, etc.
The forms don't have consistent metadata today, so a search on a category won't work for me....And IT doesn't want to keep updating a UI when a business person adds a new form....

Any ideas what I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Content Query Web Part (CQWP)
You can query the list and return the results.  You can customize the views but you need to edit the XSL to do that.  The MS documentation on how to do that is here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa981241%28v=office.14%29.aspx but if you do a search you will find many step by step examples available.

Search Web Part
With 2013 you don't need to target specific metadata - you can create rules targeting specific libraries and even specific document types inside libraries (say to filter out only word docs).  These are much easier to customize the views with compared to CQWP, using what are called display templates.  Here is a channel9 session on how to use them https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC322

Both of the above options are easy to get your data but more difficult to make them look the way you want. Another option is to use SharePoint Designer to add add an XSLT list view that connects to your document libraries.  This will only work when data is is in the same site collection, and will need SharePoint Designer to create.   Start here with that:  https://support.office.com/en-in/article/create-a-custom-list-view-using-sharepoint-designer-d0de3aa0-5e70-4ae9-bfd1-7e03a599bc73

Lastly - you can attach a workflow to document library to update your master lists whenever a new document is added.  The benefit with this approach is you can use, style, and filter with default list tools. This requires the use of SharePoint Designer.

**NOTE**:  All the options may require some sort of customization to meet your need.  They don't need VS to do them, any text editor will work, but having a tool that understands XML and/or JavaScript will be of some help (NotePad++, SharePoint Designer, etc).